# how to iterate through every element of a complicated XML tree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have declared a root this way:

```
root = ET.fromstring(xml_data)
```

and let's say I have a XML code that looks like this

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d>
                <e>
                    ...
                </e>
            </d>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

I am not too sure how to go about iterating through each of these elements in a element tree.

I've thought about doing :

```
while (True)
    for child in root
        print child.tag
```

but this ended up with this infinite output:

```
a
a
a
a
a
```

Just to give you an idea of what I am trying to do, I am passing two XML codes, one is a pretty large and complicated XML code, and the other one is just a simple XML code.
I need to find how many matching XML there are in the large XML code.

So, I will need to iterate though each element in the large XML, and compare that with each of the small XML element.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Any solution is going to be recursive

```
process_node(node n)
    do something with n.text if present
    for child in n.children
        process_node(child)
```

And at the top level

```
process_node(root)
```

Add tests for node name as needed to customize processing.

Comment: Thank you. That's a pretty simple code, but is recursion the only way to do it? If I can do it using recursion, then I must be able to do it using a loop, right? because efficiency of the program is important for this project.

Comment: Also, isn't there a built-in library function that I can use to do this? I am looking up the library, but not too sure yet.

Comment: I don't know Python, but if recursion is inefficient then I seriously doubt the language would be as popular as it is. What makes you think you can turn a recursive algorithm into a loop better than the compiler can?

Comment: @Michael Kay, thanks for the reply. I am still trying to figure it out, but I am disinclined to use recursion in my program, because that will reinitiate all the variables in it, and as far as I know, it takes up so much of memory. It probably makes my code more succinct, but maybe not efficient.

Comment: I think you misunderstand recursion.  It does not "reinitiate all the variables".  A full tutorial on recursion is beyond the scope of SO, but in this case some study and consultation with your colleagues would be well worth the time you take.  Recursion may look scary at first but it is the foundation of a large portion of computing in general. Some problems, like calculating Fibonacci numbers, are recursively defined but much better implemented lineraly.  However, there are also whole classes of problems for which recursion is the best solution.  This is one of them.